# How to wait for database data without blocking database thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading

I really like how easy it is to handle threads in Java / Android SDK. Recently I started to use `Executors`. This approach:

```
app.executeDiskIO(() -> {
    repository.saveLocation(location);
});
```

Is good in many cases, but it seems to have its flaws when things get more complicated.

I am talking about this situation:

```
app.executeDiskIO(() -> {
    List<Restaurant> restaurants = repository.nearestRestaurants();

    app.executeNetworkIO(() -> {
        for(Restaurant restaurant : restaurants) {
            RestaurantMenu menu = menuProvider.downloadMenu(restaurant);

            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                menuView.update(menu);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The above code works with three separate threads, where each thread needs to wait for the previous one to finish, before the next one can be executed. The approach above works, but **the problem is that the `diskIO` thread is blocked until `networkIO` and `UI` threads are finished as well**.

I don't really like the idea of "nested" threads. I am sure there must be some way to make threads to wait for each other in non-blocking way. Please feel free to direct me to studying material if applicable. :-)

**PS:** I am able to solve the problem above, but approach I know requires a lot more complex logic, than few lines of code needed to create "nested" threads. My question is about whether there is some simple and elegant approach so solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried looking [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)?

Comment: @Tenten Ponce No, but I will have a look, thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This would include the implementation of `executeDiskIO()` and `executeNetworkIO()`, plus a detailed explanation of how you have concluded that "the diskIO thread is blocked until networkIO and UI threads are finished as well". In Android, the "UI thread" is never "finished", using any typical definition of "finished". `runOnUiThread()` is purely asynchronous and does not block the caller.

Comment: As stated before, RxJava can solve your issue, or Kotlin Coroutines as well. These libraries are abstractions over threads, that handle multiple codeblocks and do not put them directly into a thread, but in a pool of stuff to be done. And threads/dispatchers will handle the actions as needed, when needed.